# MySQL finding unique product ids from 2 tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 tables

```
Table: Products
                productid (int)
                name (varchar)
                description (text)

Table: Sales
                salesid (int)
                productid (int)

Table: Links
                linkid (int)
                productid (int)
```

Now, I need a query that can get me total number of product-ids that are either present in sales table, or links table or both.

Help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the data is proper, you dont really need to check the products table

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM (SELECT distinct ProductId
      from Sales
     UNION -- instead of union all to ensure that only distinct values are taken
      SELECT distinct ProductId
      from Links) products
```

Comment: query gives error: productid is unknown (select count(productid))

Comment: Edited - Just try now - thats because i forgot to give a column alias.

Comment: you're welcome!.. remember you can upvote the answer too if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(ProductId) 
FROM Products
WHERE
  ProductId IN
    (SELECT ProductId FROM Sales)
OR
  ProductId IN
    (SELECT ProductId FROM Links)
;
```

---

Edit: I was making the assumption that the Sales or Links tables could contain ProductIds not in Products, which actually makes no sense in retrospect. If the ProductId fields in Sales and Links are foreign keys to ProductId in the Products table, then you could just do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ProductId) FROM
  (
    (SELECT DISTINCT ProductId From Sales)
    UNION
    (SELECT DISTINCT ProductId From Links)
  ) AS ProductIds
;
```

Comment: is there any shorter solution?

Comment: @I-M-JM: Not that I can think of. Why does the actual length of the query matter? Think about what you're asking for, and look over the query I wrote, and you'll see that it's doing the minimum amount of work necessary.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: I was looking for similar solution that is been provided by niko, or roopesh

Comment: @I-M-JM: In retrospect, I realized I was making a bad assumption. See my updated code.

Comment: @I-M-JM: I just looked over the other answers, and I guess they came to the same realization I did, just I got there later. Glad you found what you wanted.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: Thanks AgentConundrum, your help is appreciated in every manner

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for all product-ids or just unique?

To find unique ids you can use the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.ProductId) 
FROM (SELECT ProductId FROM Sales GROUP BY ProductId HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
UNION
  SELECT ProductId FROM Links GROUP BY ProductId HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) t1
```

Comment: this wont work - for eg if a product has two sales against it and no links, it wont get selected here - from the question it seems it is needed to be counted as one product in this scenario.